# Performance Issue in R

Tags: r, performance, match

In R, I am trying to create a count matrix of elements within numerous data files:

```
rnames <- c("N","A")
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=0,dimnames=list(rnames))

#loop through hundreds of large files (MB)
#make the vector "names" contain all elements within each file 
for(name in names)
{
#if name is already in the matrix increment by 1 the second row
  if(name %in% colnames(mymatrix))
  {
    mymatrix[2,name] = mymatrix[2,name]+1
  }
#else add a column to the matrix with the specified name
  else
  {
    mymatrix <- transform(mymatrix,name)
    mymatrix[2,name] = 1
  }    
}
```

I ran the Rprof command and found that the match() function probably embedded within the %in% operator is the one causing performance issues (longer execution time)

Is there a more efficient way of checking for each element in a vector if it exists in my matrix increment it, if it doesn't create a new column in the matrix with that vector element as a column name?

if you want a reproducible code here it is... but bear in mind that the names vector in my orginal code is read from big files that contain thousands of variables which are matched with an ever increasing column number in mymatrix which ultimately leads to an increase in run time:

```
rnames <- c("N","A")
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=0,dimnames=list(rnames))

#suppose this is what the first file contains
names <- c("x","y","z","x","x","y","a")

#suppose this is what the second file contains
names <- c("x","y","z","x","x","x","x","k")


  for(name in names)
  {
    if(name %in% colnames(mymatrix))
    {
      mymatrix[2,name] = mymatrix[2,name] + 1
    }
    else
    {
      mymatrix <- transform(mymatrix,name)
      mymatrix[2,name] = 1
    }

  }


the expected output
> mymatrix
   x  y  z  a  k
N NA NA NA NA NA
A  8  3  2  1  1
```

Comment: I don't see `names` in your code. Is that supposed to be `rnames`?

Comment: no, names is another vector different from rnames. I commented on how I fill in that vector but if you want the source code I can provide it: mydataframe <- readRDS(file) names <- colnames(mydataframe)

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example with minimal input and expected output? If we can't run the code, it is hard to help you.

Comment: Try [fastmatch](https://github.com/s-u/fastmatch).

Comment: I updated my question with a reproducible code and an expected output. however, the performance issue arises only when reading larger files

Comment: It seems that you could concatenate "names" from all your files to a vector and, afterwards, use `table` on the concatenated "names"

Comment: I tried fastmatch on the files in one folder and I got a slight increase in the elapsed time as opposed to using only the %in% operator. This was unexpected since I thought fastmatch would instead decrease the elapsed time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you determined that `match` was the bottleneck. It may be, but the example you provided doesn't show that.

```
rnames <- c("N","A")
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=0, dimnames=list(rnames))
set.seed(21)
names <- sample(letters, 1e6, TRUE)
Rprof()
for(name in names) {
  if(name %in% colnames(mymatrix)) {
    mymatrix[2,name] <- mymatrix[2,name] + 1
  } else {
    mymatrix <- transform(mymatrix,name)
    mymatrix[2,name] <- 1
  }
}
Rprof(NULL)
```

The results below show that the bottleneck are data.frame methods, which are called due to your use of `transform`. `transform.default` converts your matrix to a data.frame and then calls `transform.data.frame`, which includes a call to `match`.

```
R> lapply(summaryRprof(), head)
$by.self
                 self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"[<-.data.frame"     12.02    26.15      25.90     56.35
"[.data.frame"        7.22    15.71      13.32     28.98
"match"               7.20    15.67      11.40     24.80
"%in%"                2.38     5.18      12.34     26.85
"anyDuplicated"       2.22     4.83       3.08      6.70
"names"               2.16     4.70       2.16      4.70

$by.total
                 total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"[<-"                 27.06     58.88      1.16     2.52
"[<-.data.frame"      25.90     56.35     12.02    26.15
"["                   14.32     31.16      1.00     2.18
"[.data.frame"        13.32     28.98      7.22    15.71
"%in%"                12.34     26.85      2.38     5.18
"match"               11.40     24.80      7.20    15.67

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 45.96
```

Avoid the `transform` call and your code will be significantly faster. And `mymatrix2` will actually be a matrix, whereas `mymatrix` is a data.frame.

```
rnames <- c("N","A")
mymatrix2 <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=0, dimnames=list(rnames))
set.seed(21)
names <- sample(letters, 1e6, TRUE)
Rprof()
for(name in names) {
  if(name %in% colnames(mymatrix)) {
    mymatrix2[2,name] <- mymatrix2[2,name] + 1
  } else {
    mymatrix2 <- cbind(mymatrix2, matrix(c(NA,1), 2, 1, dimnames=list(rnames, name)))
  }
}
Rprof(NULL)
lapply(summaryRprof(), head)
$by.self
                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"match"              1.28    41.83       2.70     88.24
"colnames"           0.78    25.49       1.42     46.41
"is.data.frame"      0.58    18.95       0.58     18.95
"%in%"               0.34    11.11       3.04     99.35
"dimnames"           0.06     1.96       0.06      1.96
"+"                  0.02     0.65       0.02      0.65

$by.total
                total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"%in%"                3.04     99.35      0.34    11.11
"match"               2.70     88.24      1.28    41.83
"colnames"            1.42     46.41      0.78    25.49
"is.data.frame"       0.58     18.95      0.58    18.95
"dimnames"            0.06      1.96      0.06     1.96
"+"                   0.02      0.65      0.02     0.65
identical(mymatrix2, as.matrix(mymatrix))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed input, I noticed an improvement from 7.46s to 0.92 by using cbind instead of transform to process the files in just one folder. I will try it on the whole dataset next